# How do you calculate the thrust of a peltier device?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Given that blackbody radiation of a peltier device is asymmetrical, how much photon-induced thrust would a given temperature difference create in a perfect vacuum?

Let's assume a perfect vacuum and a zero thickness peltier device that is 1m^2 with 0k on one side and 100k on the other, how would you calculate the thrust from photons being emitted from the "hot" side?  Would this thrust be different if the temperatures where shifted to 1000k and 1100k?

Comment: Since blackbody scales as T$^{4}$, yes, the absolute temperatures would make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure#Radiation_pressure_by_emission) caused by the emission of blackbody radiation is $\sigma T^4/c$ where $\sigma$ is the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant), $T$ is the absolute temperature, and $c$ is the speed of light.

From this, one can calculate that in the first case the thrust is $1.9\times 10^{-8}$ newtons and in the second case it is $8.8\times 10^{-5}$ newtons.